# How to use Maven Release Plugin with Multiple Maven Projects

Tags: java, continuous-integration, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I'm using Maven 3.

I have multiple maven projects, namely: the 'data model', the 'service', and the 'presentation', split into 3 different projects. They are configured separately (ie. not using maven parent pom).

[image: project setup]

I have maven release plugin setup on my project correctly, such that when I run `mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform` on each individual project, it updates the project version (ie: from 3.4.5-SNAPSHOT to 3.4.5) as well as all the other things.

The problem here is, 'presentation' is dependent on 'service' is dependent on 'data model', and I refer to the projects in the pom files with the version number.

While I develop, say for example I would refer to 'service' in 'presentation' as 3.4.5-SNAPSHOT. But during deploy, I have to release 'service' to change the version to 3.4.5, then I have to update my version reference of 'service' in 'presentation', before I can run a release on 'presentation'.

Is there an automated way of doing this such that I don't need to update the reference of dependent projects during release?

### What I have so from thanks to below comments: Updated: 25/03/2013

Run maven with:

```
versions:use-releases -Dmessage="update from snapshot to release" scm:checkin release:clean release:prepare release:perform
```

Outcome: version updated, but release build failed.

Answer (score 4):

The [Versions Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) may help you to achieve requirement, especially the goal [versions:use-releases](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-releases-mojo.html). You may be interested in the goal [versions:use-next-releases](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-next-releases-mojo.html) and [versions:use-latest-releases](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-releases-mojo.html) as well.

#### Side Note:

Normally, the good practice is define them as a Maven Multiple Module( [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) and [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html)). This allow us to manage the version easier as the following example.

#### The parent

```
<groupId>my-group</groupId>
<artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

    .....

<modules>
    <module>my-model</module>
    <module>my-service</module>
    <module>my-ui</module>
</modules>
```

#### The my-model

```
<parent>
    <groupId>my-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>my-model</artifactId>
```

#### The my-service

```
<parent>
    <groupId>my-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>my-service</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-model</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

#### The my-ui

```
<parent>
    <groupId>my-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>my-ui</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-service</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Regarding to the above example when we release, the related version will be updated based on the parent version automatically.

Comment: versions:use-releases looks like just what I need. I'll get it setup and tested. let you know. =)

Comment: version:use-release removes 'SNAPSHOT' from the version, but as I'm running it using: "mvn version:use-release release:clean release:prepare release:perform", it gives me: 

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0:prepare (default-cli) on project [Presentation]: Cannot prepare the release because you have local modifications :
[ERROR] [pom.xml.versionsBackup:unknown]
[ERROR] [pom.xml:modified]

Comment: I'm afraid that you may need to commit the changes once before releasing. Since the versions:use-releases changes the pom.xml as it mentions about you have local modifications.

Comment: Tried it with 'version.. scm:checkin ... release ...' just now but got the following error: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0:prepare (default-cli) on project [Presentation]: Cannot prepare the release because you have local modifications : [ERROR] [pom.xml.versionsBackup:unknown]. The ideal solution is to somehow automate it...

Comment: You may need to create a profile which contains `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin` with `phase:install` and `goal:checkin`. together with the `version:use-release`. The solution may look like `mvn -Pnew-profile release...`.